# Unable to start sonar Server

Tags: windows, sonarqube

Am trying to setup a **sonar server** in my local machine.

```
 sonarServer version:-server7.9 
 Open jdk version:-Open JDK 11
 windows version:-windows10
```

These are the version i have used.When i start the server am getting the following error.

```
020.04.03 10:29:46 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2020.04.03 10:29:47 ERROR web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] Fail to start web server
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:427)
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:65)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:52)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:97)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:81)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:99)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

I have checked the port **9000**,it is not using any services.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you also provide the output of `<sonardir>/logs?web.log` this might be quiet helpful